# Example Language Definition

Tags: discrete-mathematics

```
L = {x : ∃y∈ {a, b}* : x = ya}
```

What is the Simple English description of the above statement? From what I understand, this statement describes strings with the suffix a. How is this determined?

Comment: What do you mean by $\{a,b\}^*$? I am not familiar with the * except maybe for dual spaces.

Comment: @JDoe it is the Kleene star https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kleene_star

Comment: @mrp So just to be clear: {a, b}* would be {a, b, ε}?

Comment: Or maybe it would be {a, b, ε, ab, ba, aab, bba, ...}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would describe this as 'the language of all strings over the alphabet { 'a', 'b' } which end in 'a'.  *note: here I am using the term 'language' in the sense used in the academic field 'Theory of Computation'*